# How do i access all values of keys inside a list which itself is a value of another dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
dict = {key1:"value", key2:[{id:"value21", name:"value31" }, {id:"value22",name:"value32"},{id: "899",name:"values"}], key3:"value3"}
```

I need to extract all the values of name

Comment: Are the key names surrounded in quotes? What you've written isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: `id` is a built in function.  change to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
dict = {"key1":"value", "key2":[{"id":"value21", "name":"value31" }, {"id":"value22","name":"value32"},{"id": "899","name":"values"}], "key3":"value3"}

for data in dict["key2"]:
    if "name" in data:
        print(data["name"])
```

Output

```
value31
value32
values
```

Comment: Iterating over the keys of a dict and checking if it equals a given value defeats the purpose of having a dict (O(1) lookup). You could just do `if "name" in data: print(data["name"])`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes.. true that

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question needed to be formatted correctly as the keys are strings.

```py
# make sure keys are strings
key1 = 'a'
key2 = 'b'
key3 = 'c'
name = 'name'

# make a valid dictionary

d = {key1:"value", 
    key2:[{'id':"value21", name:"value31" }, {'id':"value22",name:"value32"},{'id': "899",name:"values"}],
     key3:"value3"}

# this is a list
result = d[key2]

# inspect list
for i in result:
    if name in i.keys():
        print (i[name])
```

returns this:

```
value31
value32
values
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `dict` and `id` are reserved so I changed them to `dct` and `'id'`:

```
dct = {'key1':"value",'key2':[{'id':"value21", 'name':"value31" },{'id':"value22",'name':"value32"},{'id': "899",'name':"values"}],'key3':"value3"}
```

I also changed the keys to strings since otherwise python expects a variable name and I think that you want to iterate over the dict w/o knowing the keys in advance.

2. Iterate over the dict values and extract the names from the nested dicts in list:

```
all_names = []

for value in dct.values():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for sub_dct in value:
            try:
                all_names.append(sub_dct['name'])
            except KeyError:
                pass

print(all_names)
```

Comment: You can create code blocks using three backticks (`) on the lines before and after your code. [Formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: I know, it wasn't working... Thx for the edit, the editor was messing with me :|

Answer (score 0):

if the dict is in given format,
the following code can be used

```
dictor = {'key1':"value", 'key2':[{'id':"value21", 'name':"value31" }, {'id':"value22",'name':"value32"},{'id': "899",'name':"values"}], 'key3':"value3"}
```

the logic to get the name is:

```
def GetValues(dictionary):
    name_data = []
    for i in dictor.keys():
        if type(dictor[i]) is list:
            for i in dictor[i]:
                name_data.append(i['name'])
    return name_data

print(GetValues(dictor))
```

will get the output as

```
['value31', 'value32', 'values']
```